# Book that uses measure theory to develop multivariablee calculus

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, reference-request

I studied measure theory but I never had rigorous multivariable calculus. Now, I come to a point where I want to fill up the gaps.

What text can you recommend me? I want to be able to understand theorems like Ostrogradsky (divergence theorem) and Green's theorem. Is there maybe a measure-theoretic approach to this?

Comment: Take a look at Amann and Escher's Analysis III. They treat measure theory and develop the Bochner-Lebesgue integral before moving on to the theory of differential forms, and finally integration on manifolds

Comment: there is no relation between Green's or the divergence theorem and measure theory, these theorems are differential geometry theorems

Comment: You could read Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres or perhaps Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by Lee.

Comment: @peek-a-boo IMO the exposition of the book you said is terrible in this part (in the last half part of volume 3, that is about differential geometry). It would be infinitely better to learn differential geometry from others books and after you can come back (if you need) to the book of Amann and Escher. An easier to follow introduction to differential geometry is the textbook of Loring Tu

Comment: @Masacroso Perhaps you're right (I'm in the completely opposite situation as OP; I've had courses in Multivariable calculus at the level of Spivak's calculus on manifolds, but never any measure theory/Lebesgue integration). I referenced the text because I thought it might be something OP would like. But yea I should have probably mentioned that the book is definitely not suitable for an absolute first-time introduction to multivariable calculus

Comment: I was under the impression that you can already do a lot with the Lebesgue-integral. Fubini and stuff like that are already familiar to me. Maybe I was  mistaken?

Comment: @peek-a-boo I studied directly from the books of Amann and Escher without almost previous knowledge of mathematics, and I stopped in the half of the third volume because the exposition was not very well compared with other texts. I mean: it is entirely possible to read and learn directly from these books (as I did), however for some parts it would be better to use other textbooks. These books are good in many points but it big drawback is that it lacks motivation and context in general to properly understand things as intuitively as possible (compared with other textbooks)